# Create view is posting null objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Should be an easy question to answer.
I am trying to create an object in a view. The class that contains the object consists of a User class and a password.
When I click on the submit button, the Controller picks up null values for Password and User.
See below the Container class, the Controller and the View;

```
public class UserExtended
{
    public UserITOC User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new UserExtended());
    }

    //
    // POST: /Dinners/Create

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserExtended user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Create user in the User datatable
            SqlUsersRepository sqlRepository = new SqlUsersRepository();
            ITOCEntities db = new ITOCEntities();
            db.UserITOCs.AddObject(user.User);

            // Create user as an authenticated user within the Reader role.
            int i = user.User.EmailAddress.IndexOf('@') - 1;
            string userName = user.User.EmailAddress.Substring(0, i);
            string email = user.User.EmailAddress;
            Membership.CreateUser(userName, user.Password, email);
            Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "Reader");                // Automatically assigned as a Reader
        }
        return View(new UserExtended());
    }
```

" %>

Create

```
<h2>Create</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Forename) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Forename)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Forename)%>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Surname) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Surname)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Surname)%>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.EmailAddress) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.EmailAddress)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.EmailAddress)%>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extremely simple solution:

Change your action-signature from

```
public ActionResult Create(UserExtended user)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Create(UserExtended UserExtended)
```

That way the ModelBinder will know how to reassemble the object from Request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic! I thought the answer would be easy, but it is one of those mistakes you have to make when learning MVC, IMHO.

Comment: So true :) Glad I could help!

Comment: I had the same problem too for the last 3 days! Couldn't believe was so easy! Haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem, but found in my case that I had to match the **database table name** rather than the **type name**

- Name of the type: NonTradingDay
- Database table name: dbo.NonTradingDays (**had been pluralized**)

Create  Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NonTradingDay NonTradingDays)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.NonTradingDay.Add(NonTradingDays);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    return View(NonTradingDays);
}
```

I had tried 'NonTradingDay', but still got null; I then looked at the database table name, tried 'NonTradingDays' and the mapping was made (the argument was no longer null).

I **think** this was because I had the database context as:

```
public DbSet<NonTradingDay> NonTradingDay { get; set; }
```

Rather than:

```
public DbSet<NonTradingDay> NonTradingDays { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a new instance of UserExtended class

**return View(new UserExtended());**

instead return the object you get as the parameter

**return user**

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that the instance he gets in to the action is null...

Comment: @arame3333 did you try just returning the user var

Comment: the issue here is NOT what is being returned from the Action, it's what is posted back to the [HttpPost] Create-action. The code never reaches the return-line, so there is no reason why it should help to return only the user var.