# MVC Create returns null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a problem in my MVC project. When trying to create an object to add it to the db, it always returns null.

```
public class ListsModel
{
    public EntitiesList EntityList { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllGroups { get; set; }
}

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ListsModel model = new ListsModel();
        model.EntityList = new EntitiesList();
        model.AllGroups = managerLists.GetAllListsKeys(); //For droplist

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ListsModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.EntityList.List_CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
            managerLists.AddNewObject(model.EntityList);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And a simple  cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EntitiesList</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntityList.List_EntitityName)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AllGroups, new SelectList(Model.AllGroups),
                                    new { @class = "form-control" })
            <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntityList.List_EntitityName)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntityList.List_EntityValue)
            <input class="form-control" value="@Model.EntityList.List_EntityValue"/>
            <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntityList.List_EntityValue)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntityList.List_OrderByNumber)
            <input class="form-control" value="@Model.EntityList.List_OrderByNumber"/>
            <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntityList.List_OrderByNumber)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntityList.List_Comments)
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3">@Model.EntityList.List_Comments</textarea>
            <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntityList.List_Comments)</p>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When it's getting to the "model.EntityList.List_CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;" a null reference exception is thrown.

I tried to change the signature to "public ActionResult Create(ListsModel ListsModel)", as suggested here: [Create view is posting null objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447672/create-view-is-posting-null-objects)
But I got the same results.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: If you debug this what does `model` contain? Is `model` null? Is `model.EntityList` null? Debug is your friend! :) Place break-point on `model.EntityList.List_CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;` line and look at what everything is at that time.

Comment: Have you specified the Model in your cshtml?

Comment: Might be unrelated, but you should be using EditorFor, TextAreaFor etc

Comment: If you comment `model.EntityList.List_CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;` then are you still getting an error?

Comment: Just to clarify, ASP.NET MVC is the web front end, while Entity Framework is the database access stuff. It's a common misunderstanding; they're commonly seen together (and ASP.NET MVC projects include EF as standard) but they are actually separate. I've added the Entity Framework tag accordingly.

Comment: Btw could you provide `EntitiesList` class code?

Comment: Belogix- yes, model is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you define inputs like this:

```
<input class="form-control" value="@Model.EntityList.List_EntityValue"/>
```

For ASP MVC can collect form data, inputs should have an Name attribute corresponding with model fields.

Try to generate inputs using the standard:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntityList.List_EntityValue)
```

I suggest you inspect the differences in the html generated (to see how is asp mvc generating inputs).

Comment: IMHO this is not related to his error but worth trying.

Comment: I think it is related becouse you need a name or id on your input.

Comment: May be true cause there is no `name` attribute in `<input>` and there is also no @Model.EntityList.List_CreatedTime field in his view so there can be some problems when trying to do HttpPost...

Comment: That seems to do the job, but I'm getting an error: "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." I don;t know if it's related. The drop down return null as a vlue to the model, instead of the string selected, I don't understand why.

Comment: You should add a variable for the selectedvalue and then use it like this... @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGroup, new SelectList(Model.AllGroups, "GROUP ID COLUMN NAME", "Description COLUMN NAME", Model.SelectedGroup))

Comment: But I don't have any "ID" and "Desciption" column, the list is a string list.

Comment: 1. Input should have a "Name" tag corresponding with model fields Rather than an "Id" and you're missing the name tags for input element  2. asp.net mvc glimpse is your best friend for model binding.

Comment: @Larry Corrected: Changed Id by Name